# Merging multiple "state-change" time series

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sqlalchemy

Given a number of tables like the following, representing state-changes at time `t` of an entity identified by `id`:

```
|     A      |    |     B      |
| t | id | a |    | t | id | b |
| - | -- | - |    | - | -- | - |
| 0 | 1  | 1 |    | 0 | 1  | 3 |
| 1 | 1  | 2 |    | 2 | 1  | 2 |
| 5 | 1  | 3 |    | 3 | 1  | 1 |
```

where `t` is in reality a `DateTime` field with millisecond precision (making discretisation infeasible), how would I go about creating the following output?

```
|     output     |
| t | id | a | b |
| - | -- | - | - |
| 0 | 1  | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1  | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1  | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1  | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1  | 3 | 1 |
```

The idea is that for any given input timestamp, the entire state of a selected entity can be extracted by selecting one row from the resulting table. So the latest state of each variable corresponding to any time needs to be present in each row.

I've tried various JOIN statements, but I seem to be getting nowhere.

Note that in my use case:

- rows also need to be joined by entity `id`
- there may be more than two source tables to be merged
- I'm running PostgreSQL, but I will eventually translate the query to SQLAlchemy, so a pure SQLAlchemy solution would be even better

I've created a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0f0f9dc9307aec70ade3de052f9b12cd) with the example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `full join` and some other manipulations.  The ideal would be:

```
select t, id,
       last_value(a.a ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by t) as a,
       last_value(b.b ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by t) as b
from a full join
     b
     using (t, id);
```

But . . . Postgres doesn't support `ignore nulls`.  So an alternative method is:

```
select t, id,
       max(a) over (partition by id, grp_a) as a,
       max(b) over (partition by id, grp_b) as b
from (select *,
             count(a.a) over (partition by id order by t) as grp_a,
             count(b.b) over (partition by id order by t) as grp_b
      from a full join
           b
           using (t, id)
     ) ab;
```

Comment: @Seb . . . I fixed the typos.